# Getting the datetime index of a value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a technical analysis project for which I need to annotate the `matplotlib` chart for buy/sell signals. As I am getting data from the `yfinance` module, I automatically have a `DateTimeIndex` in my `DataFrame`.
My `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
Date        Close       Upper       SMA         Lower       Buy  Sell
2020-05-21  231.389999  219.042175  207.178002  195.313829  NaN  231.389999 
2020-05-22  234.910004  222.051354  209.420002  196.788650  NaN  234.910004
2020-05-26  232.199997  224.164115  211.655002  199.145889  NaN  NaN  
2020-05-27  229.139999  225.151643  213.966502  202.781360  NaN  NaN 
2020-05-28  225.460007  226.004370  215.530002  205.055633  NaN  NaN
2020-05-29  225.089996  226.911921  216.549001  206.186082  NaN  NaN
2020-06-01  231.910004  228.365279  218.031001  207.696723  NaN  NaN
```

When there is a not `NaN` value in the Sell/Buy column I want to get the `Date` for it.

So if the sell price is at `231.389999`, I want the date which is `2020-05-21`.

> So far I have tried:
>
> ```py
> for i in range(0, len(df['Sell'])):
>     if pd.notnull(df['Buy'][i]):
>         date = df[df['Buy'] == i].index
> ```
>
> But I get an empty list: `DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)`

Once I get the `Date` value,  I can input is as a `x-axis` value and the `y-axis` value would be the not`NaN` value for annotating the chart.

What would be the right way to get the `DateTimeIndex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by boolean masking , `notna()` and bitwise or `'|'` method:

```
result=df[(df['Buy'].notna()) | (df['Sell'].notna())]
```

**OR**

You can also do this by boolean masking, `notna()` and `any()` method:

```
result=df[df[['Buy','Sell']].notna().any(1)]
```

Now if you print `result.index` you will get:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-21', '2020-05-22'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

And Now if you print `result` you will get:

```
             Close      Upper       SMA         Lower       Buy     Sell
Date                        
2020-05-21  231.389999  219.042175  207.178002  195.313829  NaN     231.389999
2020-05-22  234.910004  222.051354  209.420002  196.788650  NaN     234.910004
```

Now If you want to visualize it...Then you can visualize this according to your need

Comment: I want to loop through all the ```datetime``` objects and create them into a value for the x-axis so that I can create buy/sell markers.

I want to do something like:
```x_line_annotation = date_object_from_the_index```

Then use:
```ax.annotate('Sell', xy=(x_line_annotation, not_NaN_value))```

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to your code:

```
>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(df.loc[df["Sell"].notna(), "Date"])
DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-21', '2020-05-22'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code** To get the index:

```
df.query('Sell.notna() | Buy.notna()').index
```

**Output:**

```
Index(['2020-05-21', '2020-05-22'], dtype='object', name='Date')
```

**Code**
To get filtered df

```
df.query('Sell.notna() | Buy.notna()')
```

**Output**

```
              Close      Upper       SMA       Lower       Buy  Sell
Date                        
2020-05-21  231.389999  219.042175  207.178002  195.313829  NaN 231.389999
2020-05-22  234.910004  222.051354  209.420002  196.788650  NaN 234.910004
```